# Unresolved reference to <symbol> in C. Makefile seems to be in order: gcc command is perfectly fine according to the suggestions

Tags: c, gcc, struct, hyperlink, compilation

I keep getting the errors:

```
/tmp/cccpx6tz.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `SCPinstance_construct'
main.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `SCPinstance_print'
main.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `SCPinstance_destruct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

in main.c:

```
    /* Load SCP data file from OR Library */ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "scpinstance.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    char * datasrc = "ORLib/scpc1.txt";

    SCPinstance scpinstance = SCPinstance_construct(datasrc);
    SCPinstance_print(&scpinstance); 
    SCPinstance_destruct(&scpinstance);  
    // 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

in  scpinstance.h:

```
#ifndef SCPINSTANCE_H
#define SCPINSTANCE_H

typedef struct {
    char * name; 
    int m; /* number of rows */
    int n; /* number of columns */
    int * c; /* costs */
    int ** J; /* list of columns that cover row i. 
                J[i][0] = length of list, index 
                list starts at 1 */
} SCPinstance;

/* SCPinstance_construct: constructor, 
    returns a SCPinstance object with data from src where src is a filename */
SCPinstance SCPinstance_construct(char * src);

/* SCPinstance_print: print values in SCPinstance */
void SCPinstance_print(SCPinstance *); 

/* SCPinstance_destruct: destructor of SCPinstance.
    returns 0 if successful. */
int SCPinstance_destruct(SCPinstance *); 
#endif
```

in scpinstance.c:

```
#include "scpinstance.h"

/* SCPinstance_construct: constructor, 
    returns a SCPinstance object with data from src where src is a filename */
SCPinstance SCPinstance_construct(char * src);

/* SCPinstance_print: print values in SCPinstance */
void SCPinstance_print(SCPinstance * scpinstance); 

/* SCPinstance_destruct: destructor of SCPinstance.
    returns 0 if successful. */
int SCPinstance_destruct(SCPinstance * scpinstance);
```

in Makefile:

```
GCC = gcc 
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wshadow
OBJS = main.o scpinstance.o

scploader: $(OBJS)
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ 

.c.o:
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -c *.c
```

The gcc commands seems to be in order. I've looked around but the only relevant suggestions seems to be to link my files properly. But i checked my directory, the files in OBJS already exists.

Please help. I really appreciate it, thanks.

**Update:** 
(Solution)

Have to make sure functions are defined, not just declared. So in scpinstance.c, I did this:

```
#include "scpinstance.h"

/* SCPinstance_construct: constructor, 
    returns a SCPinstance object with data from src where src is a filename */
SCPinstance SCPinstance_construct(char * src){
    SCPinstance scpinstance;
    return scpinstance; 
}

/* SCPinstance_print: print values in SCPinstance */
void SCPinstance_print(SCPinstance * scpinstance){

}

/* SCPinstance_destruct: destructor of SCPinstance.
    returns 0 if successful. */
int SCPinstance_destruct(SCPinstance * scpinstance){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You appear t have **two** "in scpinstance.c:", or is that a typo?

Comment: And no function definitions, only declarations.

Comment: @R.. yes, that's it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Your C source file only contains declarations of the functions, not definitions of them. As such, they have no definitions, and thus the symbols are undefined at link time.